# Правильное написание названия фильма

Tags: орфография

Как узнать правильное написание названия фильма? Например, фильм "Новый Свет" или фильм "Новый свет". Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря, что имеется в виду. Если фильм рассказывает, например, о поселке Новый Свет в Крыму, то оба слова будут с прописной буквы, если же речь не об имени собственном, то с прописной буквы пишется только первое слово - "Новый".

Comment: Имеется в виду фильм "The New World", вышедший на экраны в 2005 году

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, Новый Свет, т.к. в фильме идет речь об Америке, которая и считается Новым Светом, в противовес Старому Свету, т.е. старому и изведанному миру (Европа, Азия, Африка).

К тому же, можно было просто посмотреть [статью про фильм на википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC)).

Comment: Статью на Википедии, конечно, посмотреть можно, но не стоит забывать, что она является свободной энциклопедией и принять участие в ее правке может любой пользователь.

Answer (score 0):

Об Америке - с заглавной, словари не разнятся.